# What common word would we have after following these steps?

Tags: riddle

What common word would we have after following these steps?

> - write down a zero
> - put 50 on its left and 5 on its right
> - add 1/5 of eight at the end

Comment: To the downvoters - any specific reason for the downvotes without any commentary on an interesting question (now that I've seen the answer)? Apart from the common first-timer errors that were edited out by NL628, I don't see anything that egregious.

Comment: Didn't downvote @Phylyp, but I guess 1) Writing in caps is not acceptable pretty much anywhere on the internet, and could easily be seen as rude. 2) The puzzle was posted with no attribution. 3) It was answered in 2 minutes, so I question how interesting it actually is. 4) I don't think we should be discouraging downvotes, as they are pretty much the only way we have to control for puzzle quality.

Comment: Thanks for your response @ffao . It's just that PSE is one of those (rarer) SE sites that are friendly and welcoming to newcomers that this instance struck me as odd. If the reason for the DV is something like points 1&2, then I'd have expected a comment as well (or only that), so as to allow to OP to understand our protocol and give them a chance to correct it themselves. Your points 3 & 4 - granted, DVs are to show puzzle quality.

Comment: To me, its just that a DV without a comment very often leaves me wondering "what am I missing here?" in cases that are not clearly obvious (e.g. spam), and is probably also the reason why flagging/voting to close an answer often triggers a comment as well (to inform others/educate the OP).

Answer (score 29):

> $\bullet\ 50$ = **L** (Roman numeral)
> $\bullet\ 0$ = **O**
> $\bullet\ 5$ = **V** (Roman numeral)
> $\bullet\ \frac15$ of "eight" = **E** (first letter)
> Answer: **LOVE**

Comment: p fast nice one

Comment: Ah darn, I was trying to figure out what $25033 \div 5$ meant! Nice answer.